# How to compute Cross Entropy Loss for sequences

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have a sequence continuation/prediction task (input: a sequence of class indices, output: a sequence of class indices) and I use Pytorch.

My neural network returns a tensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length, numb_classes) where the entries are a number proportional to the propability that the class with this index is the next class in the sequence.
My targets in the training data are of shape (batch_size, sequence_length) (just the sequences of the real predictions).

I want to use the CrossEntropyLoss

My question: How do I use the Cross Entropy Loss function? Which input shapes are required?

Thank you!

Comment: Because this question is less concerned with programming and more with classification methodology and/or training parameters it is better suited for the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation page of [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) clearly states:

> **Input**: shape `(C)`, `(N, C)` or `(N, C, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K)` with `K >= 1` in the case of K-dimensional loss.
> **Target**: If containing class indices, shape `()`, `(N)` or `(N, d_1, d_2, ..., d_K)` with `K >= 1` in the case of K-dimensional loss where each value should be between `[0, C)`. If containing class probabilities, the input and each value should be between `[0, 1]`.

Just to be crystal clear, *"input"* refers to the output prediction of your model
while the *"target"* is the label tensor. In a nutshell, the target must have one less dimension than that of the input. This missing dimension in the target would contain each class logit value. Usually, we say the target is in the *dense* format, it only contains the class indices corresponding to the true labels.

The example you give corresponds to the use case of:

```
#input = (batch_size, sequence_length, numb_classes)
#target = (batch_size, sequence_length)
```

Which is the case of `#input = (N, C, d_1)` and `#target = (N, d_1)`, *i.e;*, you need to permute the axes, or tranpose two axes from your `input` tensor such that it gets a shape of `(batch_size, numb_classes, sequence_length)` which is `(N, C, d_1)`. You can do so with either [`torch.Tensor.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) or [`torch.Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html):

```
>>> input.permute(0,2,1)
```

or

```
>>> input.transpose(1,2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And what if I only want to use the last vector in the predicted sequence, so I take the sequence_length classes with the highest entry, in descending order, for my sequence prediction. The target would obviously still be the same. Now for the Cross Entropy loss my input must have the shape (N, numb_classes, sequence_length). But for every sequence element, in this approach, I would only have the values for the predicted class in every timestamp. Wich values would I use for the other classes in every timestamp?

Comment: Not sure why you would take the last `sequence_length` classes. Anyhow, you can always slice your output vector for instance: `input[:, -2:]` to take the last two elements of the sequence.